# HTML5 Safari video issues

Tags: html, video, safari, mp4, mov

Safari seems to be loading this video when it wants to, sometimes adding "http://" to the start of the url makes a difference, sometimes it doesn't.

It just wont load, or fallback to the img because its loading the video but not displaying it.

I'm honestly out of ideas, it's being super inconsistent.

Any help would be awesome:

video in jumbotron banner.

url in question here:

http://go.mmsg.com.au/authoring_maxxiaplus.html

Comment: What happens if you keep only the mp4 embeded? eg: Don't use MOV for HTML5 video tag. (also clear browser cache to be sure you're seeing the new code change).

Comment: It still displays nothing, but it will after refresh, I jquery'd this up for safari: 



window.onload = function() {
        if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1) {
    if(!window.location.hash) {
        window.location = window.location + '#loaded';
        window.location.reload();
    }
}
      }